# WSL2 Ubuntu forward service running on IP other than localhost

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, port-forwarding

I just recently configured WSL2 on my Windows to run `Ubuntu 20.04`. I have a service running in Ubuntu in an IP other than localhost (lets say its on `172.25.0.2:8888`). I need to connect to that service from Windows. Is there any way to do this? I tried `curl` to that IP from windows and the connection is timed out.

Here is the output of curl.

Curl on Ubuntu

```
sulfurizedduck@DESKTOP-JHK1DHJ:~$ curl -vvv telnet://172.25.0.2:8888
*   Trying 172.25.0.2:8888...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.25.0.2 (172.25.0.2) port 8888 (#0)
^C
sulfurizedduck@DESKTOP-JHK1DHJ:~$
```

Curl on Windows:

```
C:\Users\ASUS>curl -vvv telnet://172.25.0.2:8888
* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://172.25.0.2:8888/
*   Trying 172.25.0.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.25.0.2 port 8888 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to 172.25.0.2 port 8888: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.25.0.2 port 8888: Timed out

C:\Users\ASUS>
```

Comment: Second, when it gets moved to Super User, please include some additional information. (1) What exactly is the 172.25.0.2 IP?  Is this the eth0 address as shown by `ip addr show` or something else?  (2) Is there a corresponding route/IP on the Windows end?  `ipconfig /all` and `route print` from PowerShell would be helpful as well.  Including the (truncated) output from those commands in your question may be useful.

Comment: Finally, try troubleshooting with a different service.  For instance, go to a directory with a few (non-sensitive) files in Linux and run `python3 -m http.server 8080 --bind 172.25.0.2`.  Can you access that from a Windows browser using the `172.25.0.2:8080` address?  For reference, that works for me (using my WSL eth0 IP).

Comment: I have flagged the question to be moved, but about the IP `172.25.0.2`, it isn't the eth0 IP, but a websocket service running there. It isn't even listed on `ipconfig` on either Windows or Ubuntu. About the service running, it is not web service, so I can't run it on python. I didn't build the service from scratch, so I didn't really know how to move it into localhost. Because this is only for development purpose, I use `ngrok` to forward the service into https and access it from there for now, but I'll be delighted to know if there is some other way to forward it without ngrok.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - Been a bit hectic.  If the `curl` is working inside WSL, then that IP must be bound to a network interface in WSL.  You mentioned that it didn't show up with `ipconfig` in WSL, but that's still a Windows command.  To get the WSL interfaces, you need `ip addr show`.

Comment: I'm really grateful for the suggestion - however I'm sorry to tell you I've done my share on the project - and I have in some ways disposed the project. Since setting it up again for is very time consuming and I'm currently working on something else, I might not be able to test it soon. But if I got the time to test, I'll update the result here.

Comment: No worries - You should probably just delete the question if you aren't looking for answers on it.  If Stack behaves the same way that it does for Answers, you can always undelete the question later if you need to.